# In SharePoint online, how do we remove Content Type from the Library by using Powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, content-type

In SharePoint online, how do we remove Content Type from the Library by using Powershell ? I have tried using the CSOM code shown below but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$ctx.credentials = $creds  
$contentTypes = $ctx.web.contenttypes  
$ctx.load($contentTypes)  
$ctx.executeQuery() 

foreach($ct in $contentTypes){  
    write-host $ct.name  
} 


$ctName = "TCLDocument"
#Load the content types collection. 
$ctx.Load($ctx.Web.Lists)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
foreach( $ll in $ctx.Web.Lists)
{

    if($ll.Title -eq $ctName){
    $ctx.Load($ll.ContentTypes)

    try
    {
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    Write-Host $ll.Title -ForegroundColor Green

    foreach($cc in $ll.ContentTypes)
    {
        Write-Output $cc.Name
        if($cc.Name = "Document"){
            $ctExists = $true  
            $existingCT = $ct  
            Write-Host "Content Type $ctId 1 found" -ForegroundColor Red  
            break  
         }
    } 
    if($ctExists){  
        $existingCT.DeleteObject()  
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery() 

        Write-Host "Content Type $ctId 2 found" -ForegroundColor Red  
        break 
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the things wrong with your script is:

```
if($ll.Title -eq $ctName)
```

That means you are checking if the list title is the same as the name of a content type. I don't think that's what you want to check.

You can also try using [this script from Technet Gallery](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/SharePoint-Online-Remove-a-3a19f5b5) (aren't you using it already, just forgot to mention the source?)  or `Remove-SPOContentType` cmdlet from [this Powershell module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/SharePoint-Module-for-5ecbbcf0) - also from Technet Gallery. Sample use of the cmdlet:

```
Remove-SPOContentType -ContentTypeID "0x0100E6BD49EA28F1AE4BA49AA555FB4B179A" -ListTitle MyList6
```

Source: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32531.sharepoint-online-spomod-remove-spocontenttype.aspx 
If nothing of these will work, post an error message that you are getting.